# IE (all versions) adds "undefined" while loading content with $.post(JSON)

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json, internet-explorer

When I click a link, it redirects to a PHP file. The content is loaded and fetched as JSON and is displayed. There is no problem there.

In all versions of IE though, the content is displayed with an `"undefined"` string before the content, which is loaded with `$.post(JSON)`.

***NOTE:*** In the requested PHP file, data is send with `json_encode()`.

**jQuery code:**

```
$(".letter").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajaxSetup({cache:false});
    var letter= $(this).text();
    $.post("http://localhost/ajax.php/", {letter:letter},function(data) {
       var listdata;
       $.each(data, function(i,item) {
            listdata += "<tr>";
            listdata += "<td>"+item.book_name+"</td>";
            listdata += "<td>"+item.author+"</td>";
            listdata += "</tr>";
       });
      $("#result").empty();
      $("#result").html(listdata);
    },"json"
   );
});
```

**HTML code:**

```
<div id="letters">
  <span class="letter">A</span>
  <span class="letter">B</span>
  <span class="letter">C</span>
  <span class="letter">D</span>
</div>
<h3>My Books </h3>
<table id="result"> </table>
```

**In IE browser, display like:**

```
My Books 
undefined  

| Science and Tech | Author1 |
| Web Development  | Author2 |
```

How can I solve this IE problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to initialize `listdata` to an empty string `var listdata = '';` by default it is undefined.